# Entity Framework, efficient NavigationProperty.OfType query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm having trouble constructing an efficient query in EF4 using type per table (TPT) inheritance.

I have an entity called **Episode**,  and each episode can have multiple events. There several different type of events all deriving from a base entity called **Event**.  I want to filter on all episodes that don't contain a certain type of event.  **Episode** has a navigation property that is a collection of all its events (i.e. a collection of the base **Event** type)

I've tried:

```
from episode in context.EpisodeSet
where episode.Events.OfType<DerivedEvent>().Count() == 0
select episode
```

and

```
from episode in context.EpisodeSet
where episode.Events.Where(p => p is DerivedEvent).Count() == 0
select episode
```

Both of these produce a typical long SQL expansion that queries every **Event** type table.

Shouldn't there be a way to express this query in LINQ that just involves a join between the **Episode** and the **DerivedEvent** table in the resulting SQL?

**Edit:** 
In response to ProfessorX here is the generated SQL (basically just a typical massive union across all event tables)

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[TypeId] AS [TypeId], 
[Extent1].[PatientId] AS [PatientId], 
[Extent1].[CentreId] AS [CentreId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedOn] AS [UpdatedOn], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy]
FROM [dbo].[Episode] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM   [dbo].[Event] AS [Extent2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[InvasiveDischargableEvent] AS [Extent3] ) AS [Project1] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Project1].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll4].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [UnionAll4].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [UnionAll4].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [UnionAll4].[C4] AS [C4], 
        [UnionAll4].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [UnionAll4].[C6] AS [C6], 
        [UnionAll4].[C7] AS [C7]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [UnionAll3].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [UnionAll3].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [UnionAll3].[C3] AS [C3], 
            [UnionAll3].[C4] AS [C4], 
            [UnionAll3].[C5] AS [C5], 
            [UnionAll3].[C6] AS [C6], 
            [UnionAll3].[C7] AS [C7]
            FROM  (SELECT 
                [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C3], 
                [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C4], 
                [UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C5], 
                [UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C6], 
                [UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C7]
                FROM  (SELECT 
                    [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C1], 
                    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C2], 
                    [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C3], 
                    [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C4], 
                    [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C5], 
                    [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C6], 
                    [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C7]
                    FROM  (SELECT 
                        [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C1], 
                        cast(1 as bit) AS [C2], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C3], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C4], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C5], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
                        FROM [dbo].[InvasivePSQ10Event] AS [Extent4]
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT 
                        [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C1], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C2], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C3], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C4], 
                        cast(0 as bit) AS [C5], 
                        cast(1 as bit) AS [C6]
                        FROM [dbo].[InvasivePostTreatmentEvent] AS [Extent5]) AS [UnionAll1]
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                    [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    cast(0 as bit) AS [C1], 
                    cast(0 as bit) AS [C2], 
                    cast(1 as bit) AS [C3], 
                    cast(0 as bit) AS [C4], 
                    cast(0 as bit) AS [C5], 
                    cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
                    FROM [dbo].[InvasiveTreatmentEvent] AS [Extent6]) AS [UnionAll2]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id], 
                cast(0 as bit) AS [C1], 
                cast(0 as bit) AS [C2], 
                cast(0 as bit) AS [C3], 
                cast(0 as bit) AS [C4], 
                cast(1 as bit) AS [C5], 
                cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
                FROM [dbo].[InvasiveConsultationEvent] AS [Extent7]) AS [UnionAll3]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id], 
            cast(1 as bit) AS [C1], 
            cast(0 as bit) AS [C2], 
            cast(0 as bit) AS [C3], 
            cast(0 as bit) AS [C4], 
            cast(0 as bit) AS [C5], 
            cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
            FROM [dbo].[InvasiveMOXFQEvent] AS [Extent8]) AS [UnionAll4]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C1], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C2], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C3], 
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C4], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C5], 
        cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
        FROM [dbo].[InvasiveReferralEvent] AS [Extent9]) AS [UnionAll5] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [UnionAll5].[C1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[EpisodeId]) AND (CASE WHEN (( NOT (([UnionAll5].[C2] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C2] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([UnionAll5].[C3] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C3] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([UnionAll5].[C4] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C4] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([UnionAll5].[C5] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C5] IS NOT NULL)))) THEN '2X' WHEN (([UnionAll5].[C5] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C5] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '2X0X' WHEN (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL) AND ( NOT (([UnionAll5].[C6] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C6] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (([UnionAll5].[C7] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C7] IS NOT NULL)))) THEN '2X1X' WHEN (([UnionAll5].[C4] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C4] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '2X2X' WHEN (([UnionAll5].[C2] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C2] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '2X3X' WHEN (([UnionAll5].[C6] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C6] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '2X1X0X' WHEN (([UnionAll5].[C7] = 1) AND ([UnionAll5].[C7] IS NOT NULL)) THEN '2X1X1X' ELSE '2X4X' END LIKE '2X4X%')
)
```

Comment: As I know this cannot be fixed. TPT queries are very inefficient at the moment.

Comment: At last I've managed to find a way to make it work - and answered my own question below.  I agree there are pitfalls with TPT,  but so far I've managed to work around everything through careful use of OfType.  But I'm not sure the benefits outweight the extra care involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much head scratching I've managed to get this to work:

```
var episodes = (from episode in context.EpisodeSet
                join e in context.EventSet.OfType<DerivedEvent>() on episode.Id equals e.EpisodeId into outer
                from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where o == null
                select episode)
```

So rather than try to apply an OfType filter to the navigation property I've had to apply it to the ObjectSet and do an outer join.  Seems that OfType and 'as' type filtering don't work against Navigation Properties.

This produces the episodes that don't have a corresponding event in the DerivedEvent table,  and with the kind of SQL that you would write by hand.

The LINQ follows the way you'd naturally write the query with SQL.  It's just too easy to get seduced by all these navigation properties that lead to nice looking LINQ but awful looking SQL.

Answer (score 3):

.Any() is better than .Count()
From my prospective your query can be optimized to:

```
context.EpisodeSet
.Where(e => e.Events.Any(p => p is DerivedEvent))
.Select(e => e);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've fixed that but unfortunately it doesn't also fix the problem of the resulting SQL joining across all event type tables.

Comment: I've added the SQL resulting from the query with Any.  Not sure how useful it is as it's pretty typical of the unreadable SQL you get with TPT inheritance.  However you can see it's querying across multiple event tables rather than just doing a join on the single derived event table (which in this case is the PSQ10Event table).